# Ionic changes native clipboard copy/paste selection window layout

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I'm running through an issue with my ionic application.
I have some regular inputs and I was trying to copy and paste things inside them, but when I did longPress them, I noticed that the floating box that opens in android was really off. In iOS, this clipboard box sticks to the standard layout, but for some reason it's being altered in android.

I looked if there was a way to alter this box, but I couldn't find anything, could you guys please tell me if you ever seen something like this?

How it currently is:

[image: how it currently is]

But what I really want is something like this:

How it is supposed to be:

[image]

Comment: Hello, did you try it on web or on real device? have you tried to uninstall and install the app?

Comment: Hi! I tried on a couple of real devices and emulators and they all are behaving the same, so i don't necessarily think it's related to the android version.

Comment: Ohh i forgot to answer your second question. I did try to uninstall it, but the problem still remains.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Clipboard Plugin that Ionic offers. That'll eliminate this popup.